# Merging Two HashTable with removal of duplicates in java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, merge, hashtable

I am having two Hashtables with `<int,string>` pair. Now they both have duplicate values in each of them, and I want to merge both the hashtables to give me distinct values. How can I do that!?

thanks
**Edit #1** I am reading file contents from a directory. and storing those contents as tokens in two different hashtables. Now I need to merge them into a single hashtable which would give me distinct values of both the tables.

Comment: What's a "Hashtable with pair"? Also, are you sure you want to get rid of duplicate values, or rather duplicate keys?

Comment: sorry, i think it got edited... I meant integer,string pair. and i want to get rid of duplicate values.

Comment: No - you had not marked the angle brackets properly. As for removing duplicate values: which of the keys do you want to remove?

Comment: I am having unique int keys for each values, so theres no specific key I want to remove, I just want to merge these two tables to get an table with distinct values of both.

Comment: A Hashtable maps keys to unique values. There cannot be any duplicate entries in the two input Hashtables. There could be keys that are associated with the same value, and there could be keys that are found in both Hashtables. What do you want to happen in each case? Draw diagrams if necessary. A picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`putAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method of `Hashtable` to merge two hashtables. The hashtable passed as an argument will overwrite duplicates in the original hashtable.

I didn't get how two hashtables can be **merged** and still have **distinct** values. If you want to remove duplicate items from **one** hashtable (and leave them in the second hashtable) just do as suggested in another answer, but without adding non-duplicate items to `map2`. After that you will have the first table unmodified and the second with entries which aren't in `map1`.

Another solution is to merge two hashtables using `putAll` and clear the second hashtable :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean duplicate keys, not duplicate values. Also, since Hashtable is a map implementation, I'll provide a generic map solution.

```
// assuming the maps are of type String / String
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map1.entrySet()){
    if(map2.containsKey(entry.getKey()){
        map2.remove(entry.getKey());
    }else{
        map2.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now map2 is the merged version with all duplicates removed

---

But if you want a Map without duplicate *values*, that's pretty cumbersome to achieve. Maybe you should check out the [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html) interface in [apache commons / collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections). It provides maps were both keys and values are unique.

---

Actually, here's a simple way to remove duplicate values:

```
Collection<String> values1 = map1.values();
Collection<String> values2 = map2.values();
Collection<String> values1Copy = new ArrayList<String>(values1);
Collection<String> values2Copy = new ArrayList<String>(values2);
while(values1.removeAll(values2Copy)){}
while(values2.removeAll(values1Copy)){}
```

Now all duplicate values are removed from both maps. (This is assuming you want to delete the dupes entirely. If you want to keep one copy, use the values1 and values2 collections in the while loops and don't take copies.)

Comment: Well, that is what I am confused on. But for your info. I am editing my questions again.

Answer (score 0):

The original question-asker asserted in the comments that he means value, not key. This makes the question incomplete. In order to have duplicate values in two different tables, the key generation algorithm must be different. If that's the case, the bit of information that is missing from the question is which key does he want to retain? The one from the first hashtable or the one from the second?

The solution presented above by S.P.Floyd-seanizer is correct but needs a tiny bit of logic added if he really, really mean values. this additional logic would tell the code which key to put the thing under in the merged version.

if the question-asker is having 'value' and 'key' confusion then his solution is spot on.

Comment: Well, isnt it possible to create a new hashtable, which has no repeated values from both the tables?!

Comment: Yes, of course, but you have to choose what key you want it under. Someone above asked if you if you meant duplicate keys and you said no, duplicate values. That implies that there can be duplicate values w/o duplicate keys. In that case you have to choose what key you want the de-duplicated value in, in your resulting table.